# How to use karel.jar in eclipse without installing the Stanford version of eclipse and with JRE7?

Tags: java, eclipse, karel

I'm trying to play with Karel the robot as proposed in the CS106A online course from Stanford University. I do not want to install the old version of Java and eclipse as suggested by the documentation. I found tutorials explaining how to do it, on a standalone eclipse installation, and even a thread in stackoverflow, but they are all based on JRE6.

Is there a way to make it work with JFE7?

Thanks in advance.

Additional questions, that I will probably find obvious in the coming weeks:

- Why does this library not work with JRE7? (I expect newer lib not to work with older JRE, but no the contrary)
- How do you force the compilation with an older JRE in eclipse? Can you do it without installing JRE6?
- How can I know the compatibility of the .jar file?

Thanks again.

Comment: did you get any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same but it didn't work, you can use new eclipse but not a new jre.
in case you want to use a new eclipse you have to copy all the plugins from the old eclipse to the new one.